# transparent image in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i have made a simple design in photoshop
when i tried to put it in Xcode i had some problems with NavigationBar

i used this code to change the UINavigationBar background image (a PNG transparent image):

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController]navigationBar];
[navBar setBackgroundImage[UIImageimageNamed:@"navBar2.png"]forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
```

everything works fine but the problem is that the image appears in the navigationBar without transparency.

please someone help me to fix the transparency issue i search everywhere without any satisfied answer
NB! Im using IOS 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try setting the navigation bar to translucent.

```
[navBar setTranslucent: YES];
```

Comment: i tried to use the black translucent style, it shows the transparency... but now my UITableView is underneath the UINavigationBar see the picture bellow http://www.monsterup.com/image.php?url=upload/1343761351853.png

Comment: Just move it down in the storyboard or programatically.

Comment: not exactly what i want but it should fix my problem thanks my friend

Comment: Be aware that setting the nav bar as translucent will add a transparency to the background, so it might not be the best solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have it in your Storyboard? Try change the style of your navigation bar into black translucent.

Comment: Yes i have it in storyboard
i tried to use the black translucent style, it shows the transparency... 
but now the UITableView is underneath the UINavigationBar see the picture bellow 

http://www.monsterup.com/image.php?url=upload/1343761351853.png

Comment: isn't that what you want? to have the background underneath your navigation bar? if that's not then the easiest way to do it is to make a navigation bar with the background in photoshop and set it to be non-transparent in xcode

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the background color of the view of the navigationController the same as the backgrouond color of the main view.

```
//Set your view's background color    
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view_background"]]];

//Set your custom image for the navigationController
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"navigation_bar_image"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

//And then set the background color of the navigationController the same as the one of the view
[self.navigationController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view_background"]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
[self.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

And make sure you set up tint color to default.